# Jquery ajax mysql update before user leaves

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Hello i have coded a script to update information ones user tries to leave page but my code are not working and do not know why i need help to solve this :

jquery :

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){

   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'updateusers.php',
        data: {
            username: username,
            usertype: usertype,
            email: email,
            level: level,
            exp: exp,
            money: money,
            ninjarank: ninjarank,
            avatar: avatar,
            village: village,
            clan: clan,
            guild: guild,
            healthpoint: healthpoint,
            chakrapoint: chakrapoint,
            ninjutsu: ninjutsu,
            taijutsu: taijutsu,
            genjutsu: genjutsu,
            senjutsu: senjutsu,
            talent: talent,
            chakra: chakra,
            health: health,
            chakracontrol: chakracontrol
        }
    });
});
```

updateusers.php :

```
<?php
require "mysql.php";
session_start();

    $userid = $_POST["userid"];
    $usertyp = $_POST["usertype"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $level = $_POST["level"];
    $exp = $_POST["exp"];
    $money = $_POST["money"] + 1000;
    $ninjarank = $_POST["ninjarank"];
    $avatar = $_POST["avatar"];
    $village = $_POST["village"];
    $clan = $_POST["clan"];
    $guild = $_POST["guild"];
    $healthpoint = $_POST["healthpoint"];
    $chakrapoint = $_POST["chakrapoint"];
    $ninjutsu = $_POST["ninjutsu"];
    $taijutsu = $_POST["taijutsu"];
    $genjutsu =  $_POST["genjutsu"];
    $senjutsu = $_POST["senjutsu"];
    $talent = $_POST["talent"];
    $chakra = $_POST["chakra"];
    $health = $_POST["health"];
    $chakracontrol = $_POST["chakracontrol"];

        $stmt = $connect->prepare("UPDATE users u SET 
        u.usertype=?,
        u.email=?,
        u.level=?,
        u.exp=?,
        u.money=?,
        u.ninjarank=?,
        u.avatar=?,
        u.village=?,
        u.clan=?,
        u.guild=?,
        u.healthpoint=?,
        u.chakrapoint=?,
        u.ninjutsu=?,
        u.taijutsu=?,
        u.genjutsu=?,
        u.senjutsu=?,
        u.talent=?,
        u.chakra=?,
        u.health=?,
        u.chakracontrol=?
         WHERE userid= ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("isiiisssssiiiiiiiiiii",
                     $usertype,
                     $email,
                     $level,
                     $exp,
                     $money,
                     $ninjarank,
                     $avatar,
                     $village,
                     $clan,
                     $guild,
                     $healthpoint,
                     $chakrapoint,
                     $ninjutsu,
                     $taijutsu,
                     $genjutsu,
                     $senjutsu,
                     $talent,
                     $chakra,
                     $health,
                     $chakracontrol,
                     $userid
                         );

        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        $connect->close();
?>
```

so i try to send all information ones user tries to leave page to updateusers.php and there doing update query but for some reason its not working , i have made this just to see if its works or not $money = $_POST["money"] + 1000; i am adding +1000 on each time user leaves but nothing changed at all at database

Comment: Is all variables are global you are sending to server using ajax? And you can use `async:false` to make sure the request completed; and you can also add `ignore_user_abort();` see more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php)

Comment: i am sending SESSION variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With **beforeunload** event, you must return a message that will be alerted to user. For more detail, you can read here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload

In your case:
 1. Make sure ajax code has no errors.
 2. Add there return value to the event function.

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
   var confirmationMessage = 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'updateusers.php',
        data: {
            username: username,
            usertype: usertype,
            email: email,
            level: level,
            exp: exp,
            money: money,
            ninjarank: ninjarank,
            avatar: avatar,
            village: village,
            clan: clan,
            guild: guild,
            healthpoint: healthpoint,
            chakrapoint: chakrapoint,
            ninjutsu: ninjutsu,
            taijutsu: taijutsu,
            genjutsu: genjutsu,
            senjutsu: senjutsu,
            talent: talent,
            chakra: chakra,
            health: health,
            chakracontrol: chakracontrol
        }
    });
    e.returnValue = confirmationMessage;// Gecko, Trident, Chrome 34+
    return confirmationMessage;// Gecko, WebKit, Chrome <34
});
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: i return this but not working eather :var newvariable = alert("test");
            return newvariable;

Answer (score 0):

First you have to check that your all post value is present on updateusers.php using print_r($_POST).

Then you will see here which values are post and which are not. After that apply your condition for update.